# Differentiating a Dot Product

Tags: syntax

I apologize if this type of question has been asked before, but a preliminary search turned up nothing.

I would like to differentiate dot products. For example, consider taking a derivative with respect to the $i$-th component of $P$ in the dot product $P \cdot X$. How do I teach Mathematica that is given by

$\frac{\partial (P\cdot X)}{\partial P_i} = \frac{\partial }{\partial P_i}(P_a X^a) = \delta^i_a X^a = X^i$

? Ideally, I would like to implement/generalize this rule to dot products of vectors in special relativity where the dot product is given by $a \cdot b = \eta_{\mu\nu} a^\mu b^\nu$.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need to "teach" this to Mathematica, it knows how to take derivatives. For example, say you have arbitrary vectors `xVec={x[1], x[2], ... x[n]}` and `pVec={p[1], p[2], ... p[n]}`. Then you can take the  derivative of the dot product with respect to one of the p[]'s straightforwardly using `D`:

```
n = 5;
xVec = Array[x, n];
pVec = Array[p, n];
D[xVec.pVec, p[3]]
```

which gives the expected answer `x[3]`. You can replace the standard dot product `.` with your own function.

More generally, (as nikie points out in the comments) you can take the derivative with respect to the complete vector `pVec` using

```
D[xVec.pVec, {pVec}]
```

which gives the expected answer `{x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]}` (for `n=5`).

Comment: You can even write `D[xVec.pVec, {pVec}]` to get the gradient wrt `pVec`, or `D[xVec.pVec, {pVec, 2}]` to get the Hessian. It took me a long time to figure that out...